# SwiftMailer test username and password

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I really don't know if this is about `SwiftMailer` or `mailtrap.io` but the problem is when I try to establish a SMTP connection to said service (`mailtrap.io`) I never get any errors, even if I don't use any username or password. Am I not supposed to get any authentication errors when not using any username or password? Or am I doing this the wrong way?

This is the method I use to test if the dynamic connection can be made before I store it in the `.env` file.

```
/**
 * E-mail configuration
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function postEmailConfiguration(Request $request)
{
    # Try connecting to the SMTP
    try {

        $encryption = $request->input('encryption');
        if ($encryption == 'null') {
            $encryption = NULL;
        }

        $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport($request->input('host'), $request->input('port'), $encryption);
        $transport->setUsername($request->input('username'));
        $transport->setPassword($request->input('password'));

        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
        $mailer->getTransport()->start();

        # Update .env file
        $this->setEnvironmentValues([
            'MAIL_HOST' => $request->input('host'),
            'MAIL_PORT' => $request->input('port'),
            'MAIL_USERNAME' => $request->input('username'),
            'MAIL_PASSWORD' => $request->input('password'),
            'MAIL_ENCRYPTION' => $request->input('encryption')
        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Connection to SMTP establised and saved!');

    }

    # Could not connect to SMTP
    catch (Swift_TransportException $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Could not connect to SMTP server.<br>Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    # Could not connect to SMTP
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Could not connect to SMTP server.<br>Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: From SwiftMailer SMTP_Transport documentation: `A connection to the SMTP server will be established upon the first call to send():`

Comment: Okay, so basically I have to send a test mail to know if the authentication is successfull? I'll just try that and see if that helps. Add it as an answer and I'll check it

Comment: Well, a little bit further the documentation says, that you _can_ use `start()` method to check authentication. And for me everything works fine. Trying to authenticate gives me this:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@example.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password!".`

So maybe something is up with mailtrap.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested a connection to Gmail with [SwiftMailer 6](https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer#v6.0.1) on Symfony 4.4 and the code below (it's similar to yours) works as expected for me.

So if you want to check if the connection is established without a message sending use the next code:

```php
public function checkConnection()
{
    try {
        // Create the Transport
        $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport(
            'smtp.gmail.com',
            '587',
            'tls'
        ))
            ->setUsername('your.username@gmail.com')
            ->setPassword('yourSuperPassword');
        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

        $mailer->getTransport()->start();

        return true;
    } catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

otherwise, it throws an exception:

```
Swift_TransportException:
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "your.username@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z7sm3020898ljj.98 - gsmtp". 
Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z7sm3020898ljj.98 - gsmtp". 
Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z7sm3020898ljj.98 - gsmtp".
```